# Using Python FuelSDK to manage content with the new content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, content-builder

It looks like the ExactTarget/SFMC API for managing email templates has changed, but the FuelSDK examples have not yet been updated.

Legacy way to create an email template:
(assume ET_Client has been initialized and authenticated against SFMC)

```
NameOfTestEmail = 'My Email'
stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(False, debug, params = params)

# Create Email 
print('>>> Create Email')
postHTMLBody = ET_Client.ET_Email()
postHTMLBody.auth_stub = stubObj
postHTMLBody.props = {"CustomerKey" : NameOfTestEmail, "Name":NameOfTestEmail, "Subject" : "Created Using the PythonSDK", "HTMLBody": "<b>Some HTML Goes here</b>"}
postResponse = postHTMLBody.post()
print('Post Status: ' + str(postResponse.status))
print('Code: ' + str(postResponse.code))
print('Message: ' + str(postResponse.message))
print('Result Count: ' + str(len(postResponse.results)))
print('Results: ' + str(postResponse.results
```

How to do this using the new API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to utilize the REST API in order to perform CRUD operations on Content Builder assets. [Here are some example JSON payloads](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asset_model_examples.htm), from the documentation, on creating content using this approach.

I recommend utilizing a library, [such as Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), to easily structure your API calls to Marketing Cloud and work with the response. Here's an example function for retrieving your access token in order to help get you started:

```
def getToken():
    payload = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_secret": "clientSecret",
        "client_id":"clientID",
        "account_id":"12345"
    }
    print("\nAuthenticating...\n")
    res = requests.post("YOUR AUTH URL", data=payload)
    res.raise_for_status()
    return json.loads(res.text)["access_token"]
    print("Done.")

accessToken = getToken()
```